# Open page in a new tab with navigation in Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to open the web page in a browser's new tab using the **Navigation API** in Flutter web. However, I can use the **dart:html** package, but I am struggling to pass some parameters. Is there any way to do it with the Navigation API? Below is the code:

```
Navigator.push(
 context,
 MaterialPageRoute(
  builder: (context) => ResultPage(
   provider: provider,
   searchKeyword: _searchNumber.text,
  )),
);
```

Comment: This is not possible directly.
1. You should add route names for each page using named routes or by using packages such as auto_route(https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route) or go_router(https://pub.dev/packages/go_router).
2. Make sure the page needs only the parameters passed to a url. Only numbers and strings. 
3. Then open this URL in new page. 

That's how the web works. We cannot get around it.